# coreplot reload data not changing color

Tags: ios, core-plot, scatter-plot, reloaddata

i have a scattergraph that successfully plots. i have a NSArray of custom objects each of which contains the name for annotation, x value, y value, symbol color, symbol shape. when i load the graph it works fine. when i click on rows in a table that i use, i can hide points and change the color/shape instantly. however, the color will not change until i change the shape. i know that reload data is being called, i know that symbolForScatterPlot is being called, i also know that what i am giving to plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[point getColor]]; is infact the new color, however it wont change!

here is the code:

```
else if ([self.state isEqualToString:@"settings"]) {

        if (self.current == -1) {
            // all stats
            if ([indexPath section] == 0) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 32; k ++) {
                    [[theData sharedInstance] setTheColor:tmp index:k];
                }
            } else {
                for (int k = 0; k < 32; k ++) {
                    [[theData sharedInstance] setTheShape:tmp index:k];
                }
            }
        } else {
            // individual stats
            if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
                [[theData sharedInstance] setTheShape:tmp index:self.current];
            } else {
                [[theData sharedInstance] setTheColor:tmp index:self.current];
            }
        }
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updated" object:nil];
    }
```

which leads to:

```
-(void)performTask {
    [self.hostView.hostedGraph reloadData];
    NSLog(@"updated!");
}
```

and the symbol code:

```
- (CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol;

    DataPoint *point = [[[theData sharedInstance] getData:@"dataPoint"] objectAtIndex:index];

    plotSymbol = [point getShape];
    plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor whiteColor]];

    NSLog(@"the fill color is %@", [point getColor]);

    if ([point getPointOn]) {
        float var = [[[[theData sharedInstance] getData:@"dataPoint"]objectAtIndex:index] getStats:2005];
        plotSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(var/2, var/2);
    }
    plotSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[point getColor]];

    return plotSymbol;
}
```

i honestly have no idea why the color wont update. oh also the color will change without the shape changing when data is re-downloaded from the server and the graph is reloaded.

EDIT: as you can see in the code, i set it to white immediately after the shape, however it isnt drawn as white, it is drawn as the default color, which just confused me even more :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Core Plot bug. The plot symbol doesn't invalidate its internal cache when you change the color. Please report it on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).

Comment: so there is no fix for it? :(

Comment: Not yet. I'll try to fix it this weekend.

Comment: I just pushed an update to Google Code. Pull the latest code with Mercurial, give it a try, and let me know if it's fixed.

Comment: that works perfectly, thank you for such a quick fix! my app's looking quite nice now :)